# Why does the following code give me 0 as the output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
        float a;

        float b;
        float avg;

        avg = ((3.5 * a) + (7.5 * b))/(3.5 + 7.5);

        cout <<"AVG = ";
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << avg << endl;


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: undefined behavior

Comment: The answers already explain that it is ub. But what output did you expect?

Answer (score 5):

Using uninitialised local variables shows *undefined behavior* (UB), and there is **no proper explanation** to an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Its giving **0.00000** because you have not initialize the variables **a** and **b** with any values.
may be your compiler is initializing **a** and **b** with **0**

Comment: Please, precise that "your compiler is initializing `a` and `b` with `0`" is specific to this compiler with those specific options. Behavior observed here isn't specify by any standard

Answer (score 3):

The following code will definitely produce 0

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

float a;
float b;
float avg;

int main()
{
    avg = ((3.5 * a) + (7.5 * b)) / (3.5 + 7.5);

    cout << "AVG = ";
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << avg << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

because **global** variables of type `float` are initialized to zero by compiler.

But your original snippet is incorrect, because variables are not initialized before operation - just because compiler should not to initialize such **local** variables. Standards call that "undefined behavior", and some compiler find that as error (e.g. Visual Studio C++ compiler):

> Error 2   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'a' used  source.cpp  15
>
> Error 3   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used  source.cpp  15

Where 15th line is `avg = ((3.5 * a) + (7.5 * b)) / (3.5 + 7.5);`

Answer (score 1):

So basically this is a compiler specific thing. Your compiler seems to be initialising the variables a and b to 0. You should ideally see a warning while compiling your code that a and b are uninitialized in the function main. If you tried a different compiler it might not assign it to zero but you should get whatever value is leftover.

Answer (score 0):

Its 0 because the variables are uninitialized. Its then going to produce undefined behavior.

If you don't know what undefined behavior is, to sum it up, its just something that builds successfully, but the executable doesn't run the way it should.